# Copy Range to Named Range in different Sheets

Tags: vba, excel, range

I have a named range called "Capacities" Which refers to Sheet "Model" and Range("I13:I15")

Now in the macro below I have Range "ScnCap"

Now at the end Everything that has been commented out doesn't seems to work

Although aim is very simple I just want to assign the Named Range("Capacities") the Range("ScnCap") that's been generated in the macro.

Any Idea where I am Wrong ?

```
Dim wm, ws, wr As Worksheet
Dim i, j, l, m As Long
Dim char As Variant
Dim ScnCap As Range

Set wm = Sheets("Model")
Set ws = Sheets("Scenarios")
Set wr = Sheets("Results")

For i = 1 To 5

With ws
 j = i + 1
 .Cells(7, j).Select
  Set ScnCap = .Range(.Cells(5, j), .Cells(7, j))
 End With



' ws.Range("ScnCap").Value.Copy wm.Range("Capacities")
'wm.Range("Capacities") = ws.Range("ScnCap").Value
'
'Range("ScnCap").Copy
'Range("Capacities").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

  Next i
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ScnCap` is already a set range object, so you do not need to use the Range() method on it again.

This will work:

```
wm.[capacities] = ScnCap.Value
```